# Array replace PHP in constructor

Tags: php

Here is an example of my class, I have default options defined in the constructor and I want to replace them with any options provided.

```
class Class{
  private $options;

  function __construct($options=null){
    $this->options = array('option1'=>'value', 'option2'=>'value', ...);
    array_replace(_recursive)($this->options,$options);
  }

  function showOpts(){
    print_r($this->options);
  }
}

$opt = array('newOpt'=>value ..);
$c = new Class($opt);
$c->showOpts();
```

when I print the contents of options I get the default values without any replacement.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo (`array_replace(_recursive) should be array_replace_recursive`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because array_replace_recursive returns the resulting array.

You should assign its result to $this->options

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the options variable with the array method result.

```
function __construct($options=null){
    $this->options = array('option1'=>'value', 'option2'=>'value', ...);
    $this->options = array_replace_recursive($this->options,$options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bullet proof:

```
  function __construct($options = array()){
    $this->options = array('option1'=>'value', 'option2'=>'value', ...);
    $new_options = array_replace($this->options, $options);
    if ($new_options)
      $this->options = $new_options;
  }
```

Function definition:

`array array_replace ( array &$array , array &$array1 [, array &$... ] )`

Returns an array, or NULL if an error occurs.